# SiriKit INSearchForAccountsIntent not using CFBundleSpokenName for app name pronunciation

Tags: ios, xcode, siri, sirikit

I have a SiriKit extension in my iOS app that uses the INSearchForAccountsIntent to display account balances via the Siri interface. However, Siri pronounces the app name incorrectly and when given the correct pronunciation via setting the CFBundleSpokenName in the property list, Siri still uses the CFBundleDisplayName instead. I've seen this pointed out as a bug on Apple's side in a forum, but that was reported over 2 years ago and I'm wondering if anyone else has run into this and found a workaround?

Comment: I have the same problem, have a found a solution for this problem/bug?

Comment: Nope our workaround was to change the bundle display name unfortunately. I reached out to Apple about it but they basically said they didn’t understand the problem and gave no help.